# Python (beginner): CSV column writing, unexpected output for time-autocorrelation function

Tags: python, csv

Trying to write a fourth column to a set of data which looks like this

```
 8000.5   16745     0.1257
 8001.0   16745     0.1242
 8001.5   16745     0.1565
 8002.0   16745     0.1595
```

Which has the number of times the second number (i.e. 16745) has been counted in that particular file (it does change, the list has a couple thousand entries). i.e. if this were the whole file

```
 8000.5   16745     0.1257   4
 8001.0   16745     0.1242   4
 8001.5   16745     0.1565   4
 8002.0   16745     0.1595   4
```

The problem with my code seems to be in the writing stage, the dictionary works, and csv.reader is reading the file fine if I print it but when it comes to appending the only dictionary key it picks up (field[1]) seems to be one where 16745 is -1 and the count of this is printed in the fourth column for all rows. I can't understand why it is cross referencing with the dictionary only for this value and not on a per row basis.

i.e. I get

```
 8000.5   16745     0.1257   [count of -1 in column 2]
 8001.0   16745     0.1242   [count of -1 in column 2]
 8001.5   16745     0.1565   [count of -1 in column 2]
 8002.0   16745     0.1595   [count of -1 in column 2]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import numpy
import string
import csv
import sys
import os

time = []
water = []
itemcount ={}

global filename
filename = sys.argv[1]

f1 = open(sys.argv[1], 'rt')
for line in f1:
    fields = line.split()
    time.append(fields[0])
    water.append(fields[1])
f1.close()

for x in water:
    a = water.count(x)
    itemcount[x] = a

writerfp = open('watout.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(writerfp)
for row in csv.reader(open(filename, 'r')):
    fields = line.split()
    row.append(itemcount[fields[1]])
    writer.writerow(row)
writerfp.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your error is in the last loop.  You should drop the line

```
fields = line.split()
```

and change the next line to

```
row.append(itemcount[row[1]])
```

Your code has a few more issues:

1. You declare `filename` as global at global scope.  This is meaningless, since it would be global anyway.  Moreover, the next line in the code uses `sys.argv[1]` again.
2. You should use `with` statements to open files.
3. There is no `t` mode when opening files in Python 2.x.
4. Your algorithm to determine the counts is *very* inefficient.  You are iterating over the whole list for each entry of the list.  You can make do in a single pass.

Cleaning up all these issues and removing all the unused variables, you can get the job done with the following code:

```
import collections
with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as input:
    counts = collections.Counter(line.split()[1] for line in input)
    input.seek(0)
    with open("watout.csv", "w") as output:
        for line in input:
            count = counts[line.split()[1]]
            output.write(line.rstrip("\n") + "\t" + str(count) + "\n")
```

Comment: Thank you so much that is painfully eloquent! Also about a thousand times quicker!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the case, but maybe you're using the wrong loop variable in your last loop.

```
fields = line.split()
```

`line` doesn't change during the whole loop, so you end up using the same key with the dictionary.

Comment: Yeah this was pretty bad proofreading, there were still other problems though when I did row.append(itemcount[row[1]]) which is what I presume I meant, I still got row out of range, and when I looked at the output the list wasn't as I expected. Thanks!

Comment: @cc211: These problems are due to your use of the `csv` module, while your input wasn't comma.separated at all.  You would have needed to use further options, e.g. `delimiter="\t"`, for the `csv.reader()` and `csv.writer()` constructors.